# Indent and wrap consecutive matching lines with string

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, markdown

I would like to convert a predictably-formatted file containing code snippets into Markdown. The file looks like this:

```
MY CODE SNIPPETS          2015-05-01

This file contains useful code snippets for every day usage
in the Linux command line.

SED
  sed 's/\(.*\)1/\12/g'                  # Modify anystring1 to anystring2
  sed '/^ *#/d; /^ *$/d'                 # Remove comments and blank lines

SORT
  sort -t. -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n   # Sort IPV4 ip addresses

...
```

Lines starting with `sed` or `sort` (lowercase - may have whitespace in front) should be wrapped with ```` ``` ```` (Markdown starting / ending code markers), be indented with 4 spaces and have 1 blank line before and after the section. Consecutive lines with `sed` or `sort` should be wrapped inside the same coding section. The final Markdown file should look like this:

````
MY CODE SNIPPETS          2015-05-01

This file contains useful code snippets for every day usage
in the Linux command line.

SED

    ```
    sed 's/\(.*\)1/\12/g'                  # Modify anystring1 to anystring2
    sed '/^ *#/d; /^ *$/d'                 # Remove comments and blank lines
    ```

SORT

    ```
    sort -t. -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n   # Sort IPV4 ip addresses
    ```
````

I would be mostly interested in an `awk/sed/bash` solution, but other suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this:

````
awk '
    $1 ~ /^(sed|sort)$/ {
        print "\n    ```"
        while ($1 ~ /^(sed|sort)$/) {
            sub(/^[ \t]*/, "    ")
            print
            if (!getline) {
                print "    ```\n"
                exit
            }
        }
        print "    ```\n"
    }
    1'
````

Output:

````
MY CODE SNIPPETS          2015-05-01

This file contains useful code snippets for every day usage
in the Linux command line.

SED

    ```
    sed 's/\(.*\)1/\12/g'                  # Modify anystring1 to anystring2
    sed '/^ *#/d; /^ *$/d'                 # Remove comments and blank lines
    ```


SORT

    ```
    sort -t. -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n   # Sort IPV4 ip addresses
    ```
````

Comment: brilliant, thanks! Learned something new (`getline`)

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` variant:
(Logic is quite similar to the other answer)

````
awk '
    BEGIN{p=0}
    /^ *(sed|sort)/{
        if(!p)print "```";
        p=1;
        print "    " $0;
        next
        }
    p{
        print "```"
        p=0
     }
     1;
     END{
         if(p)print "```"
        }' my_commands.txt
````

Output:

````
MY CODE SNIPPETS          2015-05-01

This file contains useful code snippets for every day usage
in the Linux command line.

SED
```
      sed 's/\(.*\)1/\12/g'                  # Modify anystring1 to anystring2
      sed '/^ *#/d; /^ *$/d'                 # Remove comments and blank lines
```

SORT
```
      sort -t. -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n   # Sort IPV4 ip addresses
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your alternative solution. I have already accepted the other answer but yours works great too (with a nice alternative approach using the `p` flag. Two minor comments: 1. ` ``` ` should be indented as well with 4 spaces (just change to ` print "    ```"  ` 2. The regex condition of the other answer (`$1 ~ /^(sed|sort)$/`) seems to be better since it takes into account both space and tabs in front of the `sed/sort` commands (using `$1`) and the dollar `$` at the end assures that we won't match other words starting with `sed/sort`.